# background css mask transition - css shape to 100% width and height?

Tags: css-transitions, mask, css-shapes

I'm trying to realise the following:

On hover an item,

I would like the background color of my container to change with a new transition.

For this I am thinking to use a shape mask by css like a circle shape. on hover the item, the background shape will scale down to 0, then rescale at 100% with a different color. To give a bit of a nice animation.

I have the transition fine working in the fiddle below:

https://jsfiddle.net/cvcaa9k9/

However, as I would like it to have the full shape of the container, how can I achieve this ?? If I set up the circle shape to 100% nothing get display . . .

Any idea how it can be done ? Basically, I just need the shape to be done with a width and a height of 100% . ..

below my css:

```
.element {   
background-color: #c0392b;
color: white;
width:500px; 
height: 500px;
margin: 30px auto;
text-align: justify;
 transition: all 3s ease;
 /* new function syntax for webkit browsers */
 shape-inside: circle(210px);
 -webkit-clip-path: circle(210px);
  shape-padding: 15px;
}
```

Thanks for all your time, I really appreciate !

Comment: Couldn't understand what you meant. Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/cvcaa9k9/1/) what you need? If not, can you show us the demo that is *not* working so I can get a clue as to what you are looking for?

Comment: I got it working and update the jiddle at the end :)

The only thing, is I would like at the end of the animation the background to stay yellow .. .  if you have any solutions ?

Comment: add a large transition delay to make it look like its staying?

Comment: Do you mean like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/cvcaa9k9/2/)? @tibewww.

Comment: beautifull @Harry

Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: You're welcome @tibewww. By the way why are you using `shape-inside`, `clip-path`, `mask` etc for this one? I am sure you could achieve this with just one pseudo-element and transforms.

Comment: Hmmm, not ur how i Could do that, I went for what I know...

seems i have the same problem with the height, as my effect should be on a very long page, 100vh is not enough, any way to have a full height on this automatically do you think ?? ( with 100%, the animation doesnt start from 'the middle of the circle' so it looks odd)

Comment: Can you create a demo with the code that has problem?